# How do i use Batch "%user%" or "%name" command

Tags: batch-file

As The titel says, how do i make a batch script that when you for example: Enter a name and then The script responds with exact same name that The user inputted. How do i do that, help please!

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried. Have a look at `set /P` if you dont know where to start ( https://ss64.com/nt/set.html )

Comment: set /p %name%= Type your name: 
echo %name%    Or am i completely on the wrong track?

Comment: look at the exemple in the url I gave : `Set /P _dept=Please enter Department || Set _dept=NothingChosen`  then 
`If "%_dept%"=="NothingChosen" goto :sub_error`  -> dont use `%` when setting the variable

Comment: But how do i make it so they can input whatever they want. And i can avoid putting a list with names?

Comment: @YayonPlayon, not only did you come here expecting somebody else to do your work for you, which is off-topic here, but now you appear disinterested in trying the commands suggested. It is rude to expect an exact fully working script example whilst making no effort yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
@echo off
set /P "yourname=Please Enter your Name: "
echo Welcome %yourname%
```

Explained:

`set /P` is to set a variable with the *"prompt for input"* switch `/P`.
We assign the input as a variable name, which I called `yourname` then we purely echo some welcome text along with the variable we've set as `%yourname%`

For more on `set` or any other command for that matter, use the extremely helpful `/?`switch. See examples:

```
set /?
cmd /?
help
for /?
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks :D i forgot that... xD